# Linux html editor for FREE commercial license with newsletter templates and file upload

Tags: html, editor

I'm looking for a HTML editor that the customers of my web application can make email newsletters on. That works on a Linux server. I also don't have a budget for this (startup) so i'd be looking for something for free. Also, this editor must have the ability to upload files eg. logos etc...

If it had a few newsletter templates that would be a bonus ....

Thanks guys,